# Oracle comments within an anonymous block

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following code, which appears to work fine. When I add a comment within the anonymous block I get get a syntax error at line 27. The call is to a function called ddl.

How can I call the ddl function and remove the 2 lines of code directly under ddl call?

My goal is to shorten the code by calling ddl function for all the ALTER table commands.

Thanks to all who answer.

```
CREATE TABLE PARTITION_RETENTION (
   seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    RETENTION INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND(0),
 CONSTRAINT
partition_retention_pk primary key (table_name),
CONSTRAINT CHK_NON_ZERO_DAYS CHECK (
        RETENTION > INTERVAL '0' DAY
    ),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_WHOLE_DAYS CHECK (
        EXTRACT(HOUR FROM RETENTION) = 0
        AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM RETENTION) = 0
        AND EXTRACT(SECOND FROM RETENTION) = 0
    )
);

insert into PARTITION_RETENTION (TABLE_NAME, RETENTION) 
select 'T1', interval '10' day from dual union all
select 'T3', interval '15' day from dual union all
select 'T4', 15 * interval '1' day from dual union all
select 'T5', 5 * interval '1 00:00:00' day to second from dual;

CREATE TABLE t1 (     
 seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   dt   DATE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(7,'DAY'))
(
   PARTITION OLD_DATA values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
);
/

INSERT into t1 (dt)
with dt (dt, interv) as (
select date '2022-01-01', numtodsinterval(1,'DAY') from dual
union all
select dt.dt + interv, interv from dt
where dt.dt + interv < date '2022-02-01')
select dt from dt;
/



DECLARE
    CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION, -14758);

    CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION, -14083);

   ts TIMESTAMP;
 
   CURSOR TablePartitions IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, p.HIGH_VALUE, t.INTERVAL, RETENTION, DATA_TYPE
    FROM USER_PART_TABLES t
        JOIN USER_TAB_PARTITIONS p USING (TABLE_NAME)
        JOIN USER_PART_KEY_COLUMNS pk ON pk.NAME = TABLE_NAME
        JOIN USER_TAB_COLS tc USING (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME)
        JOIN PARTITION_RETENTION r USING (TABLE_NAME)
    WHERE        pk.object_type     = 'TABLE' AND
   t.partitioning_type = 'RANGE' AND 
    REGEXP_LIKE (tc.data_type, '^DATE$|^TIMESTAMP.*'); 

BEGIN

    FOR aPart IN TablePartitions LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT ts;
        IF ts < SYSTIMESTAMP - aPart.RETENTION THEN
            BEGIN
                – ddl('alter table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' drop partition '||aPart.partition_name);

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' DROP PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME|| ' UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
                 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dropped partittion '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION THEN
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cannot drop the only partition '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' TRUNCATE PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME|| ' UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Truncated partittion '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
                WHEN CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION THEN
                    BEGIN
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Drop last partittion '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL ()';
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' DROP PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME;
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL( '||aPart.INTERVAL||' )';            
                    EXCEPTION
                        WHEN CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION THEN 
                            -- Depending on the order the "last" partition can be also the "only" partition at the same time
                            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL( '||aPart.INTERVAL||' )';
                            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cannot drop the only partittion '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
                            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' TRUNCATE PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME|| ' UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
                            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Truncated partittion '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
                    END;
            END;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: a comment is two dashes  --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, there are two kinds of comments; have a look at the example:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    -- this is one-line comment
  5    select count(*) into l_cnt from dual;
  6    /* if you want, you can
  7       comment many lines. Note that
  8       those comments can't be "nested"
  9    */
 10    null;
 11  end;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of the comment of multiple lines that's very helpful